# checking an arrray and returning a bool

Tags: c, function, return, boolean

I'm in a CS class and I'm trying to create a tic tac toe program. This is my first time using functions and I need help checking a 2d array to see if it is full with 'x' or 'o' s. I initialized to start off with all the elements to '_' and I want a return value of true or false so I'm using `#include <stdbool.h>`. Here is the function:

```
bool check_table_full(char board[SIZE][SIZE]){

    if(board[0][0] == '_'){
       return false;
    }else if(board[1][0] == '_'){
       return false;
    }else if(board[2][0] == '_'){
       return false;
    }else if(board[0][1] == '_'){
       return false;
    }else if(board[1][1] == '_'){
       return false;
    }else if(board[2][1] == '_'){
       return false;
    }else if(board[0][2] == '_'){
       return false;
    }else if(board[1][2] == '_'){
       return false;
    }else if(board[2][2] == '_'){
       return false;
    }else{
        return true;
}
```

I know there is a better optimization then using if else statement but this is just is simple in my head. I use `printf("%s", check_table_full?"true":"false");` to check if it returns false as it should since all elements in the array are '_'. No matter what I do it prints true, and if I change the "true" in the printf statement it prints whatever is inside the first quote.

Everything else works like SIZE is defined, the array is defined, I just can't get this function to return false.

Sorry if this is lengthy, this is my first time asking a question on here.

Comment: are you sure you're initializing the board to all `'_'`? Have you printed out the whole board to check? What is `SIZE` defined as?

Comment: Yes I have printed out the whole array and they all are underscores and SIZE is defined as 3 to have a 3 x 3 board

Comment: BTW the function body could be `return !std::memchr(&board, '_', 9);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**If** you do `printf("%s", check_table_full?"true":"false");`, you are *not* calling the function.

`check_table_full` is the *address* of the function. You want `check_table_full()`

Comment: I was just typing the same answer. You beat me to it. :)

Comment: There should be an argument given, e.g. `check_table_full(board)`

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use nested for-loops. I have learned C++ syntax and not C syntax, so the syntax may be a little off.
Example Code...

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    char board[2][2];
    int outer_count, inner_count;
    //It will use nested for loops
    for (outer_count = 0; outer_count <= 2; count++) {
        for (inner_count = 0; inner_count <= 2; count ++) {
            if (board[outer_count][inner_count] == '_'){
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return True
}
```

Comment: This is tagged `c` [not `c++`] so `string` is not available. Also, your function falls off the end without a  `return`, so the last line should be `return true;`

Comment: Thank you Craig. I had no idea that string was not available in C. I will edit my code to reflect that, so hopefully the questionier will understand what I am saying.

Answer (score -1):

Your method of traversing the matrix is not scalable, you can easily introduce errors and is unnecessary complex. My 'check method' is 2 lines of code for any matrix size.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#define MXSIZE 3
bool is_full(char *block) {
    for (int l=0;l<MXSIZE*MXSIZE;l++)if(*(block+l)=='_')return false;
    return true;
}
int main() {
    char my2DArray[MXSIZE][MXSIZE]={{'O','O','O'},{'O','O','O'},{'O','O','_'}};
    printf("%s",is_full(&my2DArray[0][0])?"The array is full\n":"The array is not full\n");
    return 0;
}
```